# DSL query sortBy in case insensitive query formation in java, mssql DB

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, jooq, dsl

Current response a-z A-Z
Needed as aA-zZ or Aa-Zz

Code line : return select -> select.orderBy(sortFields);
Note : where *sortFields* is **List<OrderField> sortFields = new ArrayList>()**

tried using **DSL.lower menthod but it saying to convert sortFields as string.**
Code line : return select -> select.orderBy(lower(sortFields));

sortFields is in the reference of List<OrderField<?>>
is there any way to get sorting as case insensitive to get response as (aA-zZ or Aa-Zz)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer for this by adding
**Field orderFieldSort =  lower((Field) orderField);**

Comment: As I've mentioned [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74928288/521799) (implicitly), this might result in a `ClassCastException` if you have dynamic `ASC` / `DESC` sort directions, i.e. when you have `TABLE.COLUMN.asc()` in your list. You'll have to apply sort directions *after* calling `lower(f)`. If that can't happen, then you might as well maintain a `List<Field<?>>` instead of a `List<OrderField>`, in case of which your cast won't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the method signatures:

- [`SelectOrderByStep.orderBy(Collection<? extends OrderField>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/SelectOrderByStep.html#orderBy(java.util.Collection))
- [`DSL.lower(Field<?>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/dev/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#lower(org.jooq.Field))

You can't just combine them, they accept different types. The `ORDER BY` clause accepts a collection (or varargs array) of `OrderField` (`Field<?>` being a valid subtype), whereas `LOWER()` is a scalar function accepting only a single field. You can't just `LOWER()` a collection of fields. Also, you can't `LOWER()` a `SortField`, which could be something like `TABLE.COLUMN.asc()`.

I don't know why your original data structure has to be `List<OrderField>`. Are you maintaining that list somewhere to create dynamic SQL, including dynamic `ASC` / `DESC` sort order?

In any case, you will have to apply the `LOWER()` function to each field individually, e.g.:

```java
List<Field<?>> sortFields = ...
select.orderBy(sortFields.stream().map(f -> lower(f)).toList())
```

And if you have dynamic `ASC` / `DESC` sort directions, you'll have to apply that *after* calling `lower(f)` to each position.

As a side note, [collations are the SQL idiomatic way to implement case insensitive ordering](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/collations/), maybe better use that.

Comment: Yes, you are correct I'm creating dynamic SQL for my entire application. Let me try lower() for each filed